# Define all headers as a single dictionary

Tags: swagger, openapi, nswag

I'd like to define http endpoint with "any header welcome" in specification (i.e. dictionary of strings). Right now I do have to account for every single (known) header one-by-one:

```
"parameters": [
      {
        "name": "x-header-1",
        "in": "header",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "x-header-2",
        "in": "header",
        "type": "string",
      }
]
```

I'd like to define them like

```
"parameters": [
       {
          "name": "headers"
          "in": "headers"
       }
 ]
```

And ultimately in C# have a code like
`SomeMethod([FromHeader]Dictionary<string, string> ...)` for this definition.
Is this even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAPI Specification does not have a way to define arbitrary headers like in your example. Here is the corresponding enhancement request:
[Support wildcard header/parameter](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1017)

If you are designing a ***new*** API (as opposed to documenting an existing API), you can try using a single header containing comma-separated `key=value` pairs, as suggested in the comments in the link above:

```
X-MyHeader: key1=value, key2=value, key3=value
```

In OpenAPI 3.0, such header can be defined as an exploded object:

```yaml
# openapi: 3.0.3

parameters:
  - in: header
    name: X-MyHeader
    schema:
      type: object   # Free-form object
      example:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
    style: simple    # Default (and only) style for headers, can be omitted 
    explode: true
```